# python manage.py migrate Django Error

Tags: python, django, windows, cmd

I was following the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/ when i try to run `python manage.py migrate` I always get a traceback error. I even do `python manage.py makemigrations` and I still get this traceback error [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caV27.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your models

```
max_lenth
```

instead of

```
max_length
```